# Move from S3 to S3 Glacier based on Inactivity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I want to configure my storage system to move inactive files into the cold storage, AKA S3 Glacier.

The rule I'm looking for is `"if this file was not downloaded in the last 90 days, send it to S3 Glacier"`.

Lifecycle rules don't seem to work for that purpose as they don't take into account if the object is being used.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like an ideal use for the **S3 Intelligent-Tiering** storage class.

From [Using Amazon S3 storage classes - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-class-intro.html):

> **S3 Intelligent-Tiering** is an Amazon S3 storage class designed to optimize storage costs by automatically moving data to the most cost-effective access tier, without operational overhead. It delivers automatic cost savings by moving data on a granular object level between access tiers when access patterns change. S3 Intelligent-Tiering is the perfect storage class when you want to optimize storage costs for data that has unknown or changing access patterns. There are no retrieval fees for S3 Intelligent-Tiering.
>
> For a **small monthly object monitoring and automation fee**, S3 Intelligent-Tiering monitors the access patterns and moves the objects automatically from one tier to another. It works by storing objects in four access tiers: two low latency access tiers optimized for frequent and infrequent access, and two opt-in archive access tiers designed for asynchronous access that are optimized for rare access.
>
> Objects that are uploaded or transitioned to S3 Intelligent-Tiering are automatically stored in the Frequent Access tier. S3 Intelligent-Tiering works by monitoring access patterns and then moving the objects that have not been accessed in 30 consecutive days to the Infrequent Access tier. **After you activate one or both of the archive access tiers, S3 Intelligent-Tiering automatically moves objects that haven’t been accessed for 90 consecutive days to the Archive Access tier, and after 180 consecutive days of no access, to the Deep Archive Access tier.**
>
> In order to access archived objects later, you first need to restore them.
>
> **Note:** The S3 Intelligent-Tiering storage class is **suitable for objects larger than 128 KB that you plan to store for at least 30 days**. If the size of an object is less than 128 KB, it is not eligible for auto-tiering. Smaller objects can be stored, but they are always charged at the frequent access tier rates in the S3 Intelligent-Tiering storage class. If you delete an object before the end of the 30-day minimum storage duration period, you are charged for 30 days. For pricing information, see Amazon S3 pricing.

See also: [Announcing S3 Intelligent-Tiering — a New Amazon S3 Storage Class](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/s3-intelligent-tiering/)

Comment: Also, keep in mind that if you are dealing with a large number of objects, you might end up actually increasing the costs, as many objects need to be analyzed.